# How to store or forward the type of a CRTP template class

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

**General idea:** A pair of classes, a manager that creates workers. Each accepts a set of policies that customize behavior. Each policy has a part that affects the manager (does some setup) and a part that affects the worker (adds specific work functions that need to call and be called from functions in the host worker class - currently done via CRTP)

The policies used in the worker will always mirror the policies in the manager. Ie `manager<foo,bar>` will create workers of type `worker<foo_worker,bar_worker>`. Because of this I want to store the type of the worker policy in the manager policy so that the end user does not have to specify both.

The following code implements a simplified version of my code that demonstrates the problem. Look at the manager class comments. Presently (in order for the example to compile) the manager makes workers of a hard-coded type.

**Question:** How can I record the type of template class foo_worker within class foo in a way that manager can determine/look up the correct worker class based on its own template parameters?

`typedef foo_worker work_policy;` inside of `class foo` doesn't work because foo_worker isn't a class template. I have tried various sorts of wrapper classes and combinations of typename and template without luck. I have also tried having foo_worker as a nested class within foo.

I would prefer not requiring C++11 if I can avoid it, but would be willing to consider it if it radically simplifies this problem.

Is there another way to structure a system like this that avoids this issue?

Thanks in advance =)

```
#include <iostream>

// Example policy1 "foo"
template <typename worker_type> 
class foo_worker {
public:
    void policy_work() {
        std::cout << "foo_worker specific work" << std::endl;
        static_cast<worker_type*>(this)->work_finish();
    }
};

class foo {
public:
    foo() {
        std::cout << "foo setup" << std::endl;
    }
};

// Example policy2 "bar"
template <typename worker_type> 
class bar_worker {
public:
    void policy_work() {
        std::cout << "bar_worker specific work" << std::endl;
        static_cast<worker_type*>(this)->work_finish();
    }
};

class bar {
public:
    bar() {
        std::cout << "bar setup" << std::endl;
    }
};

// worker class
template <template <class> class policy1,template <class> class policy2>
class worker 
  : public policy1< worker<policy1,policy2> >,
    public policy2< worker<policy1,policy2> >
{
public:
    typedef policy1< worker<policy1,policy2> > policy1_type;
    typedef policy2< worker<policy1,policy2> > policy2_type;

    void work() {
        std::cout << "start work" << std::endl;
        static_cast<policy1_type*>(this)->policy_work();
        static_cast<policy2_type*>(this)->policy_work();
    }
    void work_finish() {
        std::cout << "finish work" << std::endl;
    }
};

// manager class
template <typename policy1,typename policy2>
class manager : public policy1, public policy2 {
public:
    // this line hard codes workers to the foo_worker and bar_worker policy. 
    // I want to be able to look up which policies to send the worker based 
    // on the policies that was given to the manager.
    typedef worker<bar_worker,foo_worker> worker_type; 

    // Would like to be able to do something like this instead:
    //typedef worker<policy1::work_policy,policy2::work_policy> worker_type;

    manager() : policy1(),policy2() {
        std::cout << "manager setup" << std::endl;
    }

    worker_type* create() {
        return new worker_type();
    }
};

int main() {
    manager<foo,bar> m;
    manager<foo,bar>::worker_type* w = m.create();

    w->work();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work something out using something like type traits? I hope I've got you correctly, so, what do you think of something like:

```
template<typename PolicyType>
struct worker_type
{
};

template<>
struct worker_type<foo>
{
    typedef foo_worker type;
};

// .... etc ...

//...

template<typename p1, typename p2>
class manager : public p1, public p2
{
    public:
        typedef worker< typename worker_type<p1>::type,
                        typename worker_type<p2>::type > worker_type;
// ...
```